# Sublime Text 3: AutoComplete from anywhere in whole project?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am wondering if there's any way to get smart autocompletion from anywhere in a Sublime project?  I found cool package called [All Autocomplete](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/All%20Autocomplete) which indexes open tabs for autocomplete... but I would love if it searched all files in project.  I can't seem to get [SublimeCodeIntel](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) to do this... maybe because SublimeCodeIntel is giving me errors in Sublime's console panel?

EDIT: Actually, it seems to autocomplete sometimes. Other times I just get the mentioned SublimeCodeIntel eval errors in console panel?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using PHP or Javascript? It can be enabling index project files:
Preferences | Package Settings | SublimeCodeIntel | Settings – Default, change the `codeintel_scan_files_in_project` to `true` in PHP/Javascript.