# How can I make Sublime Text 3 autocomplete the css class names?

Tags: sublimetext3

How I can make Sublime Text 3 autocomplete the class name of CSS from an external file like Dreamweaver?

[image: example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 3: AutoComplete from anywhere in whole project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979849/sublime-text-3-autocomplete-from-anywhere-in-whole-project)

Answer (score 2):

With a little of configuration [CSS Extended Completions](https://github.com/subhaze/CSS-Extended) should help.

> ## Usage
>
> ### Load Files From Side Bar Menu
>
> You can add files from the side bar, just right click on a folder and select the  type of files you'd like to load via `CSS Extended Completions -> [file type(s)]`
>
> This is not a recursive process, so, only the immediate files in the folder are processed, the subfolders are not processed.
>
> [image]
>
> ### Loading External Files
>
> You can eager load files from folders outside of your project via `load_external_files` setting.
>
> Example: `"load_external_files": ["/abs/path/to/css/*.css", "/abs/path/to/less/*.less"]`

Comment: i download the folder from GitHub but i don't know where i must copie it . please tell me step by step what i can do

Comment: [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3) is the easiest way. Follow instruction on this site and [usage manual](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/usage).